# Extract multiple values from JSONB in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table that looks like this:

| id | attrs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"a":{"kind":"kind_1", "value":"val_1"}, "b":{"kind":"kind_2", "value":"val_2"} |
| 2 | {"c":{"kind":"kind_3", "value":"val_1"}} |
| 3 | {"a":{"kind":"kind_1", "value":"val_1"}, "d":{"kind":"kind_4", "value":"val_4"}, ..... |

I would like to extract all the unique `value`, so the output would be:

|  |
| --- |
| val_1 |
| val_2 |
| val_4 |
| ... |

I tried to use `jsonb_each` method for it, but without any luck

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgres 12.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a JSON Path query:

```
select distinct v.item #>> '{}'
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_path_query_array(t.attrs, '$.**.value')) as v(item);
```

The `v.item #>> '{}'` is a trick to convert a scalar JSON value to `text` (because casting it wouldn't work)

Alternatively you can use jsonb_each() twice:

```
select distinct v.value
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_each(t.attrs) as i(key, item)
  cross join jsonb_each_text(i.item) as v(key, value)
where v.key = 'value'
```

---